# Maximum number of roots for the equation of type $e^x+p(x)$

Tags: exponential-function, roots

What would be the maximum number of real roots of the equation $e^x+P(x)$ where $P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree n?
I tried using induction, and for the case when $n=1$, I could visualise that the maximum number of roots would be 2, but I do not understand how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

I'll prove they can have at most $\deg(P)+1$ roots.
Induction:
$n=0$ for polynomials of degree 0 it's pretty clear.
for $n$ assuming that all polynomials of degree $n-1$ satisfy the condition.
$$f(x)=e^x + P(x),f'(x)=e^x+P'(x)$$
this means that the derivative has at most $n$ roots and thus $f$ can have at most $n+1$.
for an example for such a polynomial take:
$$e^x+mx(\prod^n_{k=0}(x-(k+1)))-1$$
for $m$ sufficiency large

Comment: Nice answer but it would be good give an example where there are exactly $n+1$ roots.

Comment: An Aside question being as we haven't set in stone the domain of $x$. I can rationalise that $f^\prime$ having at most $n$ roots implying $f^\prime$ having at most $n + 1$  roots for $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. Both $\exp$ and $P$ can be defined on all of $\mathbb C$, would your argument still be valid there @razivo?

Comment: The question specifically said "real roots", I'm not sure if it holds for $\mathbb C$

Comment: Turns out I can't read, thanks

Comment: This is great! I believe the last conclusion is from the Rolle's Theorem. Thankyou @razivo so much for this.

Comment: yes, it is a conclusion from rolle's.