# How many positive integer $y$ such that equation $4(x-1)e^x=y(e^x+xy-2x^2-3)$

Tags: inequality, exponentiation, integers

How many positive integer $y$ such that equation $$4(x-1)e^x=y(e^x+xy-2x^2-3)$$ has solution with $x\in(1,5)$

I try $e^x\leq x+1$ instead of the equation we have $g(x)= x^2(4y+2) -x(y^2+y)+2y-4=0$ but I can't check $f(x)$ with $x\in(1,5)$

After that I try with logarit but I can't fin the solution.

I try $g(x)=4(x-1)e^x-y(e^x+xy-2x^2-3)\Longrightarrow g'(x)=(4x-y)(e^x+y)$. That's enought if check the sign of $g'(x)$.

**"Source: university entrance exam in Vietnam"**

Comment: might this help? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4199161/maximum-number-of-roots-for-the-equation-of-type-expx/4199165#4199165

Comment: This is rather an unusual question. Where does it come from?

Comment: @razivo $e^x+P(x)$ don't use for this case

Comment: @TonyK university entrance exam in Vietnam

Comment: Plotting various curves with Wolfram Alpha, there seems to be a solution for $3\le y\le 14$. But I can't see how to do this by hand. (There are also solutions for negative $y$.)

Comment: I got $45$ values of $y$.

Comment: $45$ integer values of $y$.

Comment: One idea: The equation can be rewritten as
$$
e^x =\frac{2y}{4+y}x^2 + \frac{4-y^2}{4+y}x + \frac{3y}{4+y}
$$
so if you can find some criterion for when $e^x = ax^2+bx+c$ has a solution on $(1,5)$ then this might be helpful.